# How to show loading icon on scrolling in android without using listview

Tags: android

I have Scroll view as a parent and four text view inside scroll view.
I am adding data to these text view from my view class. say 15 times.now this will look like a scrolling list when i launch my app. my question is if i want to show loading symbol after say 10 items , how one can show this? Hare i am not using list view.Its just one XML and adding data externally through loop. any one know trick?

My code is some how like this-
1) textviews.xml

```
    <ScrollView>

      <TextView1/>
      <TextView2/>
      <TextView3/>
      <TextView4/>


    </ScrollView>
```

2) Viewclass.java

```
  Viewclass extends scrollview{

    for(int i=0;i<15;i++){

    View v=inflate textviews.xml;

     Textview1=(TectView)v.findviewbyid(R.id.textview1);
     Textview2=(TectView)v.findviewbyid(R.id.textview2);
     Textview3=(TectView)v.findviewbyid(R.id.textview3);
     Textview4=(TectView)v.findviewbyid(R.id.textview4);

     Textview1.setText("Hello1");
     Textview2.setText("Hello2");
     Textview3.setText("Hello3");
     Textview4.setText("Hello4");
     addView(v);
   }
 }
```

in above case how can i show loading icon after 7th element.
Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately ScrollView accepts only one child, but you can wrap it with 
FrameLayout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ScrollView
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">

       <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical>

          <TextView .... />
          <TextView .... />
          <TextView .... />
          <TextView .... />

       </LinearLayout>

     </ScrollView>

    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/loading"
         android:layout_width="100dp"
         android:layout_height="100dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:src="@drawable/loading_image"
         android:visibility="invisible" /> 

</FrameLayout>
```

So you can just change visibility of ImageView

Comment: @cyanide- how i can get scroll event .. OR how one can show after 15 items gets scrolled.

Comment: if you want the icon to scroll as well, put in a different order, so that Frame Layout is inside ScrollView:  <ScrollView><FrameLayout><LinearLayout>,,,</LinearLayout><ImageView/></FrameLayout></ScrollView>